# Working on VS Code and after making a JS file I keep getting these two errors about TypeScript and jsHint

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I saved an external JS file for a project I was working on. And when I did that at the top of my editor I got this error:

> 2.[jshint] Failed to load jshint library. Please install jshint in your workspace folder using 'npm install jshint' or globally using 'npm install -g jshint' and then press Retry.

What exactly am I supposed to do to fix these errors? I've seen other people post this issue but I don't understand the solutions that people have been giving them. Can anyone walk me through fixing these two issues in plain, easy to understand English?

Comment: Can you check that you have npm installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error means that vscode can not find an install of [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm). We use npm to install files that power IntelliSense for external modules such as `express`.

To fix it:

1. Install node/npm if you have not already: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Restart VS Code

If you still see this warning message after doing this, take a look at the [docs on this](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_fixing-npm-not-installed-warning-for-automatic-type-acquisition). The workaround is to set `"typescript.npm"` to point to where npm is installed on your computer, for example:

```
 "typescript.npm": "/Users/matb/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/bin/npm"
```

---

The second error means that vscode cannot find a copy of the jshint library. As the error messages says, the fix is to use npm to install a copy of jshint in your workspace. From a commandline in your workspace, run:

```
npm install jshint
```

For all your workspaces (globally)

```
npm install -g jshint
```

Comment: can you explain how I would run it from the command line in my workspace? Does that mean I would have to run it every time I started a new file? Its still saying that there is an error with the jshint, even though i installed node. Its saying "Please install jshint in your workspace folder using npm install jshint". Thanks for the information!

Comment: No, you only have to run it when you first open a workspace. To do so, just open the [VS Code integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) and run `npm install jshint` in it

Comment: I'm sorry I've never used terminal before. How do I do that? I accessed the terminal. should I just write it in like how you wrote it? then do I just press enter?

Comment: Yes, just paste `npm install jshint` into the terminal and then hit enter. This will run the install command. It should then print out a message saying if the install was successful or not

Comment: Oh Sweet Goodness it Worked!!! You taught me something new! Thank you! *Big Hugs and Cookies*!!!!